# postgres group by common id in array on many rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "test",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "final_zone": "ECZ", "id": 20753, "ids": "{22210,10959,22209,22213}", "sub": "{ECZECSZ,NULL,ECZECSZ,ECZECSZ}" }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "final_zone": "Protection", "id": 6516, "ids": "{24920,24943}", "sub": "{NULL,NULL}" }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "final_zone": "Protection", "id": 6524, "ids": "{24912,24920,24943,24971,24944}", "sub": "{NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}" }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "final_zone": "Protection", "id": 6528, "ids": "{24943,24958,24944}", "sub": "{NULL,NULL,NULL}" }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "final_zone": "Protection", "id": 6610, "ids": "{24943,24971}", "sub": "{NULL,NULL}" }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "final_zone": "Protection", "id": 6781, "ids": "{24912,24906,24943}", "sub": "{NULL,NULL,NULL}" }, "geometry": null }
]
}
```

In this particular instance 24943 is present in all 5 rows. how do I collapse down a table like this? and aggregate the arrays into 1 smooth array.

Keep in mind there are thousands of other rows so I dont want one massive group by. I want JUST the rows that have the same common ID in the ids array to be collapse down

[image]

I can do this

```
with abid as(
select regexp_replace(id,'[{}]','','gi')::int id from(
    select unnest(ids) id from(
        select string_to_array(ids,',') ids from conflict.test
        )t
    )t2
),
abid2 as(select ids::int[] id from conflict.test
    )
select t2.*,t.* from abid t,abid2 t2 where t.id =any(t2.id)
```

just to give a little more scope the brown middle piece below has the id of 24943 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Is not so clear the result you want, if you just want to unify the array, try this:

```
with tmp as (
select unnest(ids) ids
from your_table_name
group by unnest(ids)
)
select x.final_zone, x.id, array_agg(t.ids), x.sub, x.polys
from tmp t
cross join your_table_name x
group by x.final_zone, x.id, x.sub, x.polys;
```

Comment: what Im trying to say is if you look at the ids column, the number 24943 is present in every row. so I want to collapse these rows where they are all in one array